# Get Twitter profile url from Firebase OAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello i want to get a profile Url from the Firebase OAuth response, currently firebase give this about the profile :

```
displayName, email, photoURL,  uid
```

Have you any idea if its possible ?

(I work with a serverless project)

Comment: is this helpful? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

Comment: It's just those four fields in the Twitter providerData object, there's nothing extra?

Comment: @Rup no, only the same data that i already have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get additional user info when the sign in attempt resolves:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider())
  .then(function(userCredential) {
    // All additional user info is available here.
    console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.profile);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```

For more on this, check [`firebase.auth.UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential).

Comment: Perfect, it return the screen name and id, i can now create the profile url !

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this from Node, however, Google/Firebase Auth does not store a user's Twitter handle (at least it's not accessible through `firebase-admin`).

However, they do make the Twitter uid accessible as the question points out. With that, you can subsequently call Twitter's API to get a user by their uid and the result will return the handle:

```
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';
const BEARER = process.env['TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN'] as string;

const logTwitterHandleFromUid = async (): Promise<void> => {

  // UID for https://twitter.com/StackOverflow
  const details = await new TwitterApi(BEARER).v2.user('796800233011298304');

  // pull out the Twitter handle
  const twitter_handle = details.data.username;

  return console.log(twitter_handle);
};
```