# How to properly get Twitter screenName from firebase auth?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

Following these links https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information

I was able to authenticate user and log in with their twitter account. However, I want to get the `screenName` of an user. How will I do that?

I've checked some network request and I see the `screenName` attribute. I've checked `onAuthStateChanged` and it returns `user` attribute but without the `screenName`.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771583/get-twitter-profile-url-from-firebase-oauth/51795476

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this from Node, however, Google/Firebase Auth does not store a user's Twitter handle (at least it's not accessible through `firebase-admin`).

However, they do make the Twitter uid accessible as the question points out. With that, you can subsequently call Twitter's API to get a user by their uid and the result will return the handle a.k.a username:

```
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin';
const BEARER = process.env['TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN'] as string;

const logTwitterHandleFromUid = async (googleUid: string): Promise<void> => {

  // get Google Auth information associated with the target user
  const { providerData } = await auth().getUser(googleUid);

  // pull out the Twitter information
  const twitter = providerData.find((p) => p.providerId.includes('twitter'));

  if (!twitter) {
     console.error('User does not have a linked Twitter account')
     process.exit(1)
  }

  const details = await new TwitterApi(BEARER).v2.user(twitter.uid);

  // pull out the Twitter handle
  const twitter_handle = details.data.username;

  return console.log(twitter_handle);
};
```

Answer (score -4):

See [Get a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) documentation. The `.displayName` property should have it.

> ```
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
> var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
>
>
> if (user != null) {
>   name = user.displayName;
>   email = user.email;
>   photoUrl = user.photoURL;
>   emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
>   uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
>                    // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
>                    // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
> }
> ```

Comment: `screenName` is twitter's attribute for username. i.e. @twitter. it seems `currentUser` doesn't provide additional info like `screenName`