# How to get Twitter username from Firebase Authentication - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase twitter authentication for my project. The auth variable returning the credentials does not contain the account's twitter username but everything else.

I need to work with the username, is there a way to work around this?
Users shown in the console look like this[Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trkBl.jpg)

How do I get the respective identifier of a uid?

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, TwitterAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-auth.js";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const provider = new TwitterAuthProvider();

const auth = getAuth();


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', authenticate);

function authenticate() {
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
  
      const credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      const secret = credential.secret;

      const user = result.user;
      console.log(result)
    }).catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      const email = error.email;
      const credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Is there a way to get the username from this 'auth' variable, check below code for ref

```
import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-auth.js"

const auth = getAuth();
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user){
    // window.location.href = "/home/index.html"
  }else{

  }
})
```

Comment: You should post the part of your code where you make the request

Comment: I have added my code now, you can check it

Comment: This should still work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771583/get-twitter-profile-url-from-firebase-oauth. If you've tried that but are not getting the screen name, edit your question to show what you tried please.

Comment: I can get screen name easily, I want the username

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean Twitter handle (also called screen name) by "username"

```
 const provider = new TwitterAuthProvider();
 const userInfo = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
 console.log(userInfo._tokenResponse.screenName) // twitter handle
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you can try this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider())
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // here you get the username
    console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.username);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error occurred");
  });
```

or else you can get the info using this if you are having id :

```
let url = `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=${the_uid_from_provider_data}`;
fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        let data = response.json();
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle the error
    });
```

Comment: I actually use modular javascript, and within it also it doesn't have a key called 'additionalUserInfo' and in the second method it is saying you have no access according to CORS Policy. Can you DM me https://twitter.com/_pratikpakhale on twitter

Comment: Actually, API ask the bearer token, which is not provided by the firebase provider

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like that

```
  const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  const user = res.user;
  const username = user.reloadUserInfo.screenName;
  console.log(`username @${username}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "getAdditionalUserInfo" from "firebase/auth".

```
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
   .then((result) => {
      const additionalUserInfo = getAdditionalUserInfo(result);
  }).catch((error) => {
   // your code
  });
```